# redis in docker Permission denied

Tags: docker, redis

```
docker run -d --name=Redis \
--restart=always \
--network=host \
-v /usr/local/redis:/redis \
-v /usr/local/pki:/pki \
-u redis:redis \
redis:7.2.1 \
redis-server /redis/redis.conf
```

log is

```
Opening the temp file for AOF rewrite in rewriteAppendOnlyFile(): Permission denied
```

Adding --privileged=true doesn't help either.